# SwiftUI text alignment challenge

Tags: swiftui

The container size is fixed (200 *60), but the text length varies. Which is the best way to implement this kind of effect (red text is always at the right bottom) in SwiftUI?

- truncation + ellipsis and not overlap the red text

[image]

Comment: Do you mean the trucation? The line switching? Scaling of text? More info would be needed to give any help.

Comment: YES, truncation + ellipsis and not overlap the red text. Thanks

Comment: You'll need AttributedString